# Can someone tell me why my javascript click isnt working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Every time I press the button on in my HTML file that says "next Geocache", it doesn't work. What it supposed to do is take certain values from an array written in JSON format and apply them to the top and left style properties of the 'target' div in HTML, which contains a image of a small black square. The u/v values are supposed to be the x/y values for pixels on the photo I posted below. The button is supposed to go through the each array object every time its clicked and loop to the first element when it reaches and display the final one. I've tried everything please help!

[image of the area of the gps where the div is supposed to update on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCRwV.png)

[the image that's in the target div in the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVspe.gif)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("togglegps").onclick = togglegps;
  document.getElementById("update").onclick = updateCache;
}

var id = null;
var firstTime = -1;

var loc1 = {lat: 43.773488, lon: -79.506507, v: 294, u: 299, desc: "Top right corner of building 15"};
var loc2 = {lat: 43.774472, lon: -79.507444, v: 199, u: 282, desc: "Top right corner of building 90"};
var loc3 = {lat: 43.774841, lon: -79.500962, v: 289, u: 628, desc: "Top right corner of building 24"};
var caches = new Array();
caches[0] = loc1;
caches[1] = loc2;
caches[2] = loc3;
var currentCache = 0;


function updateCache() {
  if (currentCache <= caches.length) {
    caches[currentCache++];
    showCache();
  }
  else if(currentCache > caches.length) {
    currentCache = 0;
    showCache();
  }
}

function showCache() {
  var target = document.getElementById("target");
  target.style.top = caches[currentCache].v;
  target.style.left = caches[currentCache].u;
}


function togglegps() {
    var button = document.getElementById("togglegps");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        if (id === null) {
            id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, handleError, {enableHighAccuracy : true, timeout: 1000});
            button.innerHTML = "STOP GPS";
            firstTime = -1;
        } else {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
            id = null;
            button.innerHTML = "START GPS";
        }
    } else {
        alert("NO GPS AVAILABLE");
    }
}

function handleError(error) {
    var errorstr = "Really unknown error";
    switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        errorstr = "Permission deined";
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        errorstr = "Permission unavailable";
        break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        errorstr = "Timeout";
        break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        error = "Unknown error";
        break;
    }
    alert("GPS error " + error);
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude");
    var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude");
    var now = document.getElementById("now");

    latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
    if (firstTime < 0) {
      firstTime = position.timestamp;
    }
    now.innerHTML = position.timestamp - firstTime;

    //var gps1 = {lat: 43.774570, long: -79.510475, v: 130, u: 143};
    //var gps2 = {lat: 43.773404, long: -79.499578, v: 665, u: 399};
    var gps1 = {lat: 43.7746309, long: -79.5104764, v: 130, u: 143};
    var gps2 = {lat: 43.7735501, long: -79.4995539, v: 665, u: 399};
    var gpsi = {lat: position.coords.latitude, long: position.coords.longitude};

    function interpolateU() {
      var u_i = gps1.u + (gps2.u - gps1.u)*(gpsi.long - gps1.long)/(gps2.long - gps1.long);
      return u_i;
    }

    function interpolateV(){
      var v_i = gps1.v + (gps2.v - gps1.v)*(gpsi.lat - gps1.lat)/(gps2.lat - gps1.lat);
      return v_i;
    }

    var ui = interpolateU();
    var vi = interpolateV();

    var debug = document.getElementById("debug");
    debug.innerHTML = "(" + Math.round(vi) + ", " + Math.round(ui) + ")";

    var x = vi;
    var y = ui;
    var me = document.getElementById("me");

    me.style.top = y;
    me.style.left = x;
}
```

```css
#map {
  position: relative;
}
#target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px
}
#me {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="gps.js"></script>
  <link href="gps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Geocaching</h1>
  <div id="map">
    <img id="map" src="campus_map.png" alt="Campus Map">
    <div id="target">
      <img src="target.gif" alt="Target">
    </div>
    <div id="me">
      <img src="me.gif" alt="Me">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button id="togglegps">Start GPS</button>
    <button id="update">Next Geocache</button>
    Lattitude <span id="latitude"> ???? </span>
    Longitude <span id="longitude"> ???? </span>
    Now <span id="now"> ???? </span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="debug">debug</div>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you know what this is all about?:

    "message": "SyntaxError: missing variable name",
    "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
    "lineno": 169,
    "colno": 4

Comment: you have a typo ... `onlclick` should be `onclick`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! But the program is still not working

Comment: Please review [ask] and update this to be a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*). Currently what you have is a work order and not a question.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to debug your code! you need to be specific about the issue you have, instead of copy / pasting your entire code and expecting the community to debug it for you. as suggested by @zzzzBov do read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The bottom of your JavaScript code was cut off.
- I also enhanced the logic in `updateCache()` so that it cycles through the list of caches
  without error.
- You cannot use `window.caches` because [it is a
  browser feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/caches).
- I am also calling `showCache()` on load since I
  thought that made sense.
- Any other modifications are left as an
  exercise for the reader.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("togglegps").onclick = togglegps;
  document.getElementById("update").onclick = updateCache;
}

var id = null;
var firstTime = -1;

var loc1 = {
  lat: 43.773488,
  lon: -79.506507,
  v: 294,
  u: 299,
  desc: "Top right corner of building 15"
};
var loc2 = {
  lat: 43.774472,
  lon: -79.507444,
  v: 199,
  u: 282,
  desc: "Top right corner of building 90"
};
var loc3 = {
  lat: 43.774841,
  lon: -79.500962,
  v: 289,
  u: 628,
  desc: "Top right corner of building 24"
};
var _caches = new Array();
_caches[0] = loc1;
_caches[1] = loc2;
_caches[2] = loc3;
var currentCache = 0;


function updateCache() {
  if (currentCache >= _caches.length - 1) {
    currentCache = 0;
    showCache();
  } else if (currentCache < _caches.length - 1) {
    currentCache++;
    showCache();
  }
}

function showCache() {
  console.log('showing cache ' + _caches[currentCache].desc);
  var target = document.getElementById("target");
  target.style.top = _caches[currentCache].u;
  target.style.left = _caches[currentCache].v;
}


function togglegps() {
  var button = document.getElementById("togglegps");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    if (id === null) {
      id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, handleError, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 1000
      });
      button.innerHTML = "STOP GPS";
      firstTime = -1;
    } else {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
      id = null;
      button.innerHTML = "START GPS";
    }
  } else {
    alert("NO GPS AVAILABLE");
  }
}

function handleError(error) {
  var errorstr = "Really unknown error";
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      errorstr = "Permission deined";
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      errorstr = "Permission unavailable";
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      errorstr = "Timeout";
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      error = "Unknown error";
      break;
  }
  alert("GPS error " + error);
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude");
  var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude");
  var now = document.getElementById("now");

  latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  if (firstTime < 0) {
    firstTime = position.timestamp;
  }
  now.innerHTML = position.timestamp - firstTime;

  //var gps1 = {lat: 43.774570, long: -79.510475, v: 130, u: 143};
  //var gps2 = {lat: 43.773404, long: -79.499578, v: 665, u: 399};
  var gps1 = {
    lat: 43.7746309,
    long: -79.5104764,
    v: 130,
    u: 143
  };
  var gps2 = {
    lat: 43.7735501,
    long: -79.4995539,
    v: 665,
    u: 399
  };
  var gpsi = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    long: position.coords.longitude
  };

  function interpolateU() {
    var u_i = gps1.u + (((gps2.u - gps1.u)) * ((gpsi.long - gps1.long) / (gps2.long - gps1.long)));
    return u_i;
  }

  function interpolateV() {
    var v_i = gps1.v + (((gps2.v - gps1.v)) * ((gpsi.lat - gps1.lat) / (gps2.lat - gps1.lat)));
    return v_i;
  }

  var ui = interpolateU();
  var vi = interpolateV();

  var debug = document.getElementById("debug");
  debug.innerHTML = "(" + Math.round(vi) + ", " + Math.round(ui) + ")";

  var x = vi;
  var y = ui;
  var me = document.getElementById("me");

  me.style.top = y;
  me.style.left = x;
}

showCache();
```

```css
#map {
  position: relative;
}
#target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px
}
#me {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Geocaching</h1>
  <div id="map">
    <img id="map" src="campus_map.png" alt="Campus Map">
    <div id="target">
      <img src="target.gif" alt="Target">
    </div>
    <div id="me">
      <img src="me.gif" alt="Me">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button id="togglegps">Start GPS</button>
    <button id="update">Next Geocache</button>
    Lattitude <span id="latitude"> ???? </span>
    Longitude <span id="longitude"> ???? </span>
    Now <span id="now"> ???? </span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="debug">debug</div>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for asking this but could I updated the code so it is not cut off anymore, could you please take a look and tell me whats wrong so I can fix it?

Comment: I updated the JavaScript in my answer so the last few lines match yours. It should still work the same way.

Comment: Thank you for all the help today Dan. I'm going to be honest here, when I asked this question, I knew that it was basically asking people to do the work for me. I only asked because I was out of options. I wasn't sure why my program was working and online validators weren't helping me at all. I'm really sorry that I asked this but for what it's worth this was a great help! Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors apart from the `onclick` typo:

`function interpolateU() {` needed ==> `}`

```
var offSety = gps1.u;
    var
```

you have not declared any variable after `var`

Snippet below

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("togglegps").onclick = togglegps;
  document.getElementById("update").onclick = updateCache;
}

var id = null;
var firstTime = -1;

var loc1 = {
  lat: 43.773488,
  lon: -79.506507,
  v: 294,
  u: 299,
  desc: "Top right corner of building 15"
};
var loc2 = {
  lat: 43.774472,
  lon: -79.507444,
  v: 199,
  u: 282,
  desc: "Top right corner of building 90"
};
var loc3 = {
  lat: 43.774841,
  lon: -79.500962,
  v: 289,
  u: 628,
  desc: "Top right corner of building 24"
};
var caches = new Array();
caches[0] = loc1;
caches[1] = loc2;
caches[2] = loc3;
var currentCache = 0;


function updateCache() {
  if (currentCache <= caches.length) {
    caches[currentCache++];
    showCache();
  } else if (currentCache > caches.length) {
    currentCache = 0;
    showCache();
  }
}

function showCache() {
  var target = document.getElementById("target");
  target.style.top = caches[currentCache].u;
  target.style.left = caches[currentCache].v;
}


function togglegps() {
  var button = document.getElementById("togglegps");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    if (id === null) {
      id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, handleError, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 1000
      });
      button.innerHTML = "STOP GPS";
      firstTime = -1;
    } else {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
      id = null;
      button.innerHTML = "START GPS";
    }
  } else {
    alert("NO GPS AVAILABLE");
  }
}

function handleError(error) {
  var errorstr = "Really unknown error";
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      errorstr = "Permission deined";
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      errorstr = "Permission unavailable";
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      errorstr = "Timeout";
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      error = "Unknown error";
      break;
  }
  alert("GPS error " + error);
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude");
  var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude");
  var now = document.getElementById("now");

  latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  if (firstTime < 0) {
    firstTime = position.timestamp;
  }
  now.innerHTML = position.timestamp - firstTime;

  //var gps1 = {lat: 43.774570, long: -79.510475, v: 130, u: 143};
  //var gps2 = {lat: 43.773404, long: -79.499578, v: 665, u: 399};
  var gps1 = {
    lat: 43.7746309,
    long: -79.5104764,
    v: 130,
    u: 143
  };
  var gps2 = {
    lat: 43.7735501,
    long: -79.4995539,
    v: 665,
    u: 399
  };
  var gpsi = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    long: position.coords.longitude
  };

  function interpolateU() {
    var u_i = gps1.u + (((gps2.u - gps1.u)) * ((gpsi.long - gps1.long) / (gps2.long - gps1.long)));
    return u_i;
  }

  function interpolateV() {
    var v_i = gps1.v + (((gps2.v - gps1.v)) * ((gpsi.lat - gps1.lat) / (gps2.lat - gps1.lat)));
    return v_i;
  }

  var ui = interpolateU();
  var vi = interpolateV();

  var debug = document.getElementById("debug");
  debug.innerHTML = "(" + Math.round(vi) + ", " + Math.round(ui) + ")";

  var x = vi;
  var y = ui;
  var me = document.getElementById("me");
  var offSety = gps1.u;
}
```

```css
#map {
  position: relative;
}
#target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px
}
#me {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="gps.js"></script>
  <link href="gps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Geocaching</h1>
  <div id="map">
    <img id="map" src="campus_map.png" alt="Campus Map">
    <div id="target">
      <img src="target.gif" alt="Target">
    </div>
    <div id="me">
      <img src="me.gif" alt="Me">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button id="togglegps">Start GPS</button>
    <button id="update">Next Geocache</button>
    Lattitude <span id="latitude"> ???? </span>
    Longitude <span id="longitude"> ???? </span>
    Now <span id="now"> ???? </span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="debug">debug</div>
  </p>
</body>
```